# Angular 2 validation together with the child component

Tags: angular

Inside the parent component I have a child component. Both have their required fields. At the end I need the enable the submit button only if both components are valid (all their required fields are filled in this case).

How can I accomplish this, especially with template-driven validation?

**Seed code**

**parent component**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'parent-comp',
    templateUrl: 'parent.html'
})
export class Parent {

}

<input pInputText name="txt1" id="txt1"
                       required/>

<child-comp></child-comp>

<button pButton type="button" label="Submit"
            [disabled]="IF ONE OF THE COMPS IS NOT VALID"></button>
```

**child component**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'child-comp',
    templateUrl: 'child.html'
})
export class Child {

}

<input pInputText name="txt2" id="txt2"
                       required/>
```

Answer (score 7):

For validating both parent and child component, a single form need to be divided into multiple component.
**Parent html**

```
<form #parentForm="ngForm">
            <input pInputText name="txt1" id="txt1"
                   required/>

      <child-comp></child-comp>

        <button pButton type="button" label="Submit"
        [disabled]="!parentForm.valid"></button>
        </form>
```

**Parent Component**

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';
 @Component({
       selector: 'parent-comp',
        templateUrl: 'parent.html'
})
export class Parent {

}
```

**Child Form** must not have form tag

```
<input pInputText name="txt2" id="txt2"
                   required/>
```

**Child Component**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlContainer, NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
selector: 'child-comp',
templateUrl: 'child.html',
viewProviders: [{ provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: NgForm }]
 })
 export class Child {
 }
```

Comment: This worked for me.  Only had to import the ControlContainer and NgForm, and add the viewProviders. Quick and simple.

Answer (score 2):

You can create `@Output` variable in child that will emit form.valid value. You need to use `FormBuilder` and `FormGroup` (don't see it here).

Every time you change something inside form, you need to call a function that will emit `onchange`.

Example for child:

```
@Output onchange: EventEmitter<Boolean> = new EventEmitter(false);
formInChild: FormGroup;

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
  this.formInChild = fb.group(...)
  this.formInChild.valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
    this.onchange.emit(this.form.valid);
  }
}
```

Now in parent:

(view)

```
<child-comp (onchange)="setButtonState($event)"></child-comp>
<button pButton type="button" label="Submit"
            [disabled]="!allvalid"></button>
```

(component)

```
formInParent: FormGroup;
allvalid: boolean = false;

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
  this.formInParent = fb.group(...);
}

setButtonState(formFromChildValid) {
  this.allvalid = this.formInParent.valid && formFromChildValid;
}
```

In this case every time you change something in child's form, child's form valid state will be emitted to parent which will update `allvalid` variable which is listened by button.