# How to check the validity of the child component form within the parent component in Angular 4

Tags: forms, angular, angular2-forms

I have a scenario where I am accessing two different NgForm one within Parent form #parentform and other in the Child component #childForm, and i want to check the validity of the controls of child form wether valid or not in parent component form. How to do this in angular4.

I also followed this link:
[Check if a form is valid from a parent component using Angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44943981/check-if-a-form-is-valid-from-a-parent-component-using-angular-4)

everytime i am getting undefined for the reference of child component form.

My code is something like this.

parent.component.html

```
    <form class="form-wrapper" (ngSubmit)="parentForm.form.valid && save()" #parentForm="ngForm" novalidate>
        <input id="firstName" type="text" placeholder="" class="validate" name="firstName" [(ngModel)]="firstname_" #firstName="ngModel" required>                        
    </form>
    <child-component></child-component>
```

child.component.html

```
 <form class="form-wrapper" (ngSubmit)="childForm.form.valid && save()" #childForm="ngForm" novalidate>
        <input id="phoneNumber" type="text" placeholder="" class="validate" name="phoneNumber" [(ngModel)]="phone_" #phoneNumber="ngModel" required>                        
 </form>
```

Now i want to validate the child component form "childForm" valid or not in parent form

Comment: Can you setup reproduction on stackblitz?

Comment: Okay. I will do the same and let you know in few minutes

Comment: Please follow the link... https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cjorjz. Now i want to disable the save button until both the form controls are invalid only after the valid of both the forms i want to enable the button

Comment: How to access the NgForm using reference variable ?? Something like parentForm.form.valid and childForm.form.valid ??

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-42ai2t?file=app/parent/parent.component.html

Comment: Ok great what if i want to enable/disable particularly for each form. Like if my parent form is valid then save button gets enable and if i enter phone number then again save gets enable like separation of concern for each respective form ?? is it possible ?? Because I have collapsible component total 3 tabs.. now for each tab i am using same button "Save"  for all 3 tabs. Each tab has different forms... So 1st tab f1, 2nd tab f2, 3rd tab child component form.... So whatever form i editing i should be able to access each form and its dirty state..

Comment: `How to access the NgForm using reference variable ?? Something like parentForm.form.valid and childForm.form.valid` https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mgrgvj?file=app/parent/parent.component.html

Comment: Great @yurzui. thanks a lot for the help really damn good, just saved my time thank you. your solution is exactly what i was looking for.. Thank you very much

Comment: @yurzui last but not the least what if my child component has multiple forms ?? how to achieve then??

Comment: There are `ViewChildren` for that purpose

Comment: Can you narrate in the stackblitz with one scenario ??

Comment: You can create separate question with prepared example

Comment: Okay... but when i am using same as prepared example i am facing error 'Cannot read property 'form' of undefined' and this gives me error at return this.childComponent.form; line .... what should is do??

Comment: Posted new question for multiple forms within child component check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47552708/how-to-validate-the-child-component-ngforms-having-3-different-ngform-from-the-p

Comment: It works!!! Thanks.....

Comment: You can try something like this in the first answer of this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42955606/angular-2-validation-together-with-the-child-component